# Controlling access from C# code while uploading photos

Tags: c#, storage

I am using Google Storage Buckets to store photos from C# application.

Already bucket "ABC" with public access of 'Subject to object ACLs'. Whenever new photos upload from C# code, all these photos default by public access, but now no public access by default.

How can I make it from C# code while uploading photos?

### My C# Code:

```
        string bucketName = "bucket.com";
        string sharedkeyFilePath = @"file.json";

        GoogleCredential credential = null;
        using (var jsonStream = new FileStream(sharedkeyFilePath, FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(jsonStream);
        }

        var gcsStorage = StorageClient.Create(credential);

        string filePath = @"D:\Photos\Dummy.jpg";
        
        using (var f = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            string objectName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            gcsStorage.UploadObject(bucketName, objectName, null, f);
           
        }
```

Using C#, I tried to upload.